# Not able to create a file using Pointers in C?

Tags: c

I have created a program that creates a text file, asks the user to input any data, and then saves it and then copies the same content in another file but in Upper-Case. But whenever i start it in Netbeans it just stop in milliseconds without doing anything. Here is my complete code:

```
int main() {

FILE *f;
FILE *g;
char c, d;

f = fopen("/Users/Mansoor/Desktop/GRIMM2.txt", "r");

if (!f) {
    printf("File Couldn't be Opened.");
} else {
    printf("File opened successfully.\n");
    printf("Write Anything: ");

    while ( c != EOF ) {
        c = getchar();
        putc(c, f);
    }
    printf("Wrote Successful.\n");
    fclose(f);
}
f = fopen("/Users/Mansoor/Desktop/GRIMM2.txt", "r");
g = fopen("/Users/Mansoor/Desktop/GRIMM4.txt", "w");

while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    d = toupper(c);
    putc(d, g);
}
printf("Converted to Upper Case and copying in new file... Successful!");

fclose(f);    
fclose(g);
}
```

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in your code. You use the local variable `c` before you initialize it. Uninitialized local variables have an indeterminate value, and using them leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, you open the file `f` initially for *reading* and the you *write* to it.

Comment: Funny that the two while loops do essentially the same thing (shuttle characters between streams), but the first one is broken, but the second one looks ok.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i didn't knew that. thanks

Comment: Halfway down when you open `f` and `g` you never check for success. And `c` must be an `int`, not a `char`. `fgetc` and `getchar` return an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change first "r" to "r+" or "w" and I think when you first created the program you already had that "GRIMM2.txt" file thats why it worked.

Comment: There's also the little issue of the uninitialized `c`